# Flutter: youtube_player_flutter how to BoxFit.cover?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: height ?? context.height * 0.225,
        width: width ?? context.width * 0.65,
        child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    child: YoutubePlayer(
      controller: youtubeVidPlayerG.youtubeController(
          youtubeIDs, randomNum, mute),
      bottomActions: [],
      onEnded: (d) async {
        youtubeVidPlayerG
            .youtubeController(youtubeIDs, randomNum, mute)
            .load(
              youtubeIDs[(youtubeIDs.indexOf(d.videoId) + 1) %
              youtubeIDs.length],
            );
      },
    ),
  )
```

Video 1

[image]

Video 2

[image]

I am using `youtube_player_flutter` package to display youtube videos. I want to stretch the video to cover up the empty side. I'd tried using BoxFit.fill and BoxFit.cover but both do not fill the empty area. It has a black area on the top and bottom.

How can I stretch the video to cover up the Sizedbox's height and width?

Some videos are fully covered by the SizedBox like video 1. However, Video 2 has some leftovers on the top and bottom. I want to stretch Video 2 to look like Video 1 (I do not really mind the video looking a bit stretched).

Comment: Attach a screenshot of what you have currently and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Oh yeah. I should have done it when I wrote the question. I just attached the pictures.

Comment: Did you able to figure out this? I also need help on this. let me know if you got the solution

Comment: No hahah I gave up lol. But if I do i will comment ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FullScreen Support

If fullscreen support is required, wrap your player with **YoutubePlayerBuilder**

```
YoutubePlayerBuilder(
    player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
    ),
    builder: (context, player){
        return Column(
            children: [
                // some widgets
                player,
                //some other widgets
            ],
        );
    ),
),
```

Comment: It is not in full-screen mode. It is just covering up the container. Like how the picture gets stretched to cover all the empty spot.

Comment: Use that player get from builder inside your cliprrect